# Labeling a density plot

Tags: r, plot, label

In the following plot how can I have only the standard deviation's values printed along the x axis?

R prints 5, 7, 10, 13, 15, 19, 20, 22, 25.

```
x <- rnorm(3e3, 16, 3)
plot(density(x), type = "l", lwd = 2, col = 254,
main = "Random Variable X", xact = "n")
axis(side = 1, at = c(7, 10, 13, 19, 22, 25),
labels = c("7","10","13","19", "22", "25"))
abline(v = 16, lwd = 2)
abline(v = c(7, 10, 13, 19, 22, 25), col = "darkgreen")
```

Thank you..

Comment: You seem to have a typo in your plot statement.  where you wrote `xact = "n")`  I think you meant `xaxt = "n")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
x <- rnorm(3e3, 16, 3);
plot(
    density(x), 
    type = "l", lwd = 2, col = 254,
    main = "Random Variable X", xaxt = "n");
axis(
    side = 1, 
    at = mean(x) + seq(-3, 3, by = 1) * sd(x),
    labels = seq(-3, 3, by = 1));
```

[image]

The x-axis shows sd units in the region [-3σ, +3σ].

Answer (score 1):

Here's another method.

Another variant of the same would be to remove `x <- scale(x)` and have `y <- dnorm(x, mean(x), sd(x))`. I guess it is easy to see what I did.

The difference between this method and using `density(x)` is that how the density is estimated.

If you know the distribution in parametric, the normal distribution in this case, and it is possible to estimate the maximum likelihood estimates, `mean(x), sd(x)`, you might as well use those to estimate the density.

```
set.seed(42)
rnorm(3e3, 16, 3)

# normalize N(0, 1)
x <- scale(x)
# order so plotting is easy
x <- x[order(x)]
# density 
y <- dnorm(x)
plot(x, y, type = "l", lwd = 2, col = 254, ylab = "density", 
    main = "Random Variable X")
```

[image]